# How to track the order generated in agent population in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent population named parcelstationses with population number 3. I am generating demand of the Parcelstation using Event. Please check the image below,

[image]

In the Main agent, I want to track the order generated for each Parcelstation. How can I achieve that?

I tried using parcelstationses.get(0).amount;. But since the order generated is of type Order (another agent type). I get the following error,

cannot convert from order to double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just track the number of orders?

1. add a variable of type `int` to `Main`, called `counter`
2. in your `generateDemand` event, add a line `main.counter++`

To keep full details?

1. add a variable of type `LinkedHashMap<Order, ParcelStation>` named `myOrders` with initial value `new LinkedHashMap<Order, ParcelStation>()`
2. in your `generateDemand` event, add a line `main.myOrders.put(order, center);`

In any case, start understanding data types, model hierarchy and how to use access them, see https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to and the help on data types in general